# content replace function: replacing a space with an underscore

Tags: javascript, replace

Here is my function:

```
function process() {
var content = document.getElementById('content').value;
content = content.replace(/(<tt>(.*?)<tt>)/g, '$2');
document.getElementById('content').value = content;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<textarea id="content" cols="48" rows="8"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" value="Process" onclick="process()" />
```

Sample code:

```
<tt>hello<tt>
```

The purpose of my question is to find out if I can replace a "space" with an "underscore"
For instance, currently if you were to take my sample code from above and run it through my function you will omit this following code:

```
hello
```

and if you were to run this code:

```
<tt>hel lo<tt>
```

Through the function, this will be your result:

```
hel lo
```

the result I would prefer would be:

```
hel_lo
```

Which replaces the space with a underscore. I do realize I could insert something like this:

```
content = content.replace(/()/g, '_');
```

Into my function, But if were to do that and then run this code below:

```
<tt>d j<tt>1 2
```

then the result would be

```
d_j1_2
```

instead of what I would prefer which would be

```
d_j1 2
```

To summarize, I would like to replace a space with a underscore but only between my

```
<tt><tt>
```

tags. Help is always appreciated and thank you very much in advance. I will provide this link to my example as well: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WVUYX/40/)

Comment: Do you mean `<tt></tt>`, like normal HTML tags? What do you expect to happen if I have `<tt>bl ah<tt>he llo<tt>`?

Comment: I used this example for simplicity. But yes I would use `<tt></tt>` instead of `<tt><tt>` but it was irrelevant in this example

Comment: Okay, just making sure you understood the difference. Glad you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way that came to mind is as follows:

```
content = content.replace(/(<tt>(.*?)<tt>)/g, function(m,p1,p2) {
             return p2.replace(/ /g,"_");
          });
```

The [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a callback in the second parameter so that you can do custom processing on the match(es). The callback receives the match and submatches as parameters, and whatever your callback returns will be used as the replacement text, so you can replace the spaces on just the second submatch.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WVUYX/42/

Comment: thank you for your expedient and informative response. Your answer worked quite well.