# content replace function

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a follow up question to [content replace function:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917545/content-replace-function-replacing-a-space-with-an-underscore)

This is my current content replace function:

```
content = content.replace(/(<t t>(.*?)<t t>)/g, function(m,p1,p2){
    return p2,p1.replace(/     /g,"_").replace(/<t t>/g,"<html>");
});
```

When I run:

```
This <t t>this a test<t t> of
```

through my HTML process text area:

```
<textarea id="content" cols="48" rows="8"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" value="Process" onclick="process()" />
```

I will receive this as an output:

```
This <t_t>this_a_test<t_t> of the replace.
```

Rather than what I would want which would be this:

```
This <t d>this_a_test<t d> of the replace.
```

I know that the reason

```
<t t>
```

does not replace with

```
<t d>
```

is because my function is looking for a space and in turn will omit that space and create an underscore. But I cannot figure out how to not have that happen, whilst still replacing a space with an underscore within my two tags, e.g.

```
this a test
```

will become

```
this_a_test
```

The answerer to my previous question used this useful resource [.replace() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to help me understand, but much to my chagrin I could not figure this out myself. Thank you very much ahead of time for your help, if need be here is a link to my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/WVUYX/43/)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Please clarify.

Comment: I would like to change my current function so that when `This <t t>this a test<t t> of the replace.` is entered in to my process text area the result would be this `This <t d>this_a_test<t d> of the replace.` I apologize for the confusion, if there still is any please let me know

Answer (score 0):

So, according to your comment...

> ...so that when "This <t t>this a test<t t> of the replace". is entered in to my process text area the result would be this "This <t d>this_a_test<t d> of the replace"...

... you can simply do:

```
content.replace(/<t t>/g, "<t d>");
```

Keep in mind that the `/g` flag in regular expressions matches all patterns in the tested string (g stands for "global").

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I believe we are on the right track, but take this for  example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/WVUYX/44/). The `<t t>` will effectively replace to `<t d>` but the "is a test" portion will not be altered to elimanate spaces and add underscores. The opposite is true in this example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/WVUYX/45/).